# GTM Marketing Tag from Ecommerce Purchase

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

I want to capture only the "item_name" from my purchase dl for my other marketing tags. In this case, the dataLayer variable isn't helping. I can't use "ecommerce.items" since it gives the complete item information. Therefore I used a below JSV but I am getting the value in an array. How can I get it in text form separated by comma(,)?

JavaScript Variable in the GTM:

```
var itemslist = [];
  var products = {{dl - ecommerce - item name}};
  for(i=0; i < products.length; i++){
  itemlist.push(
    'item_name': products[i].item_name
 )
}                
return itemlist;
```

Datalayer variable in GTM: ecommerce.items

Below is the complete dataLayer:

```
{
   "event": "purchase",
   "ecommerce": {
      "transaction_id": 0000,
      "affiliation": "xxxx",
      "value": 222,
      "currency": "USD",
      "coupon": "No coupon",
      "items": [
         {
            "item_id": "4291",
            "item_name": "xyz",
            "affiliation": "xxx",
            "coupon": "No coupon",
            "item_category": "us",
            "currency": "USD",
            "discount": "0.00",
            "index": 0,
            "price": 111,
            "quantity": 1
         },
         {
            "item_id": "xxx",
            "item_name": "abc",
            "affiliation": "xxx",
            "coupon": "No coupon",
            "item_category": "us",
            "currency": "USD",
            "discount": "0.00",
            "index": 1,
            "price": 111,
            "quantity": 1
         }
      ]
```

I tried using For loop in java script variable but it is not helping. I want item names in text format.

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemslist = [];
  var products = {{dl - ecommerce - item name}};
  for(i=0; i < products.length; i++){
  itemlist.push(
    'item_name': products[i].item_name
 )
}                
return itemlist.join(',');
```

Edited:

I see the problems now from this `How can I get it in text form separated by comma(,)?`

So you want to transfer something like

[a, b, c] to "a, b, c"

Above the code will work. You just need to join the array

---

Edited

Looks like I didn't see the push value is error from your code

```
var itemslist = [];
  var products = {{dl - ecommerce - item name}};
  for(i=0; i < products.length; i++){
  itemlist.push(products[i].item_name)
  // Here should only just push the name in it without key.
}                
return itemlist.join(',');
```

Sorry about that and you can try again.

Comment: Thank you for providing the code. But unfortunately it is not working. I used the below code it is giving me only 1 item name but in string which is good. I an attaching the screenshot for the dataLayer variable.

function() {
 var products = {{dl - ecommerce - item name}}
for(var i=0; i < products.length; i++) { 
return(products[i].item_name);
}
}

Screenshot for dataLayer variable: https://ibb.co/vkN3Qq0

Comment: I don't know why but I am getting the below error
...........................
Error at line 6, character 14: Parse error. ',' expected
...........................
I tried ',' but it is giving undefined values :(